# parsing XML to base64 and json

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing, base64

I am trying to encode an XML to Base64 and then, write this Base64 to a JSON file.
When i do it, the Base64 is complete, but the JSON is incomplete, there is no trailing `}` at the end of string and it is incomplete, I do not know what could be do.

Here is my code:

This is the Xml to Base64 encoder

```
 public static String fileEncoderBase64() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("/root/EntradaN1.xml");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String linea;
    String lineas = null;

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((linea = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineas += linea;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    return encodeBase64(lineas);
}
public static String encodeBase64(String mensaje) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = mensaje.getBytes("UTF-8");
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

And this is the JSON parser:

```
public static void jsonCreator(JsonModelAgent jsonModelAgent) throws IOException {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(jsonModelAgent, new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/root/datos.json")));
}
```

And this is de diferences between mongo's Base64 length and json's length.

```
JSON: ==============>65176
MONGO: =============>76592
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you provide the expected JSON and the one that you get from your code ? I do not see any reason while the Base64 encoding and the Gson serializer will fail. What is the conversion between the Base64 string (result of  `fileEncoderBase64`) and the `JsonModelAgent` ?

Comment: Who closes the writers in the json function ? That's rule number one of Java IO : always close the streams/readers/writers (in a finaly clause). `fileEncoderBase64` is OK (although swallowing the exception is quiete unsafe, but this is not the question you're asking), but `jsonCreator` looks suspicious.

Comment: Was the fileWriter.close(), thanks mate, it works fine

Comment: @Lifestorm could you mark this question as "Answered" please.

Answer (score 0):

just adding close to jsonCreator's fileWriter works